# How to create table (SQL) for storing products information

Tags: postgresql

I have been doing quite a few tutorials such as [SqlBOLT](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/) where I have been trying to learn more and more regarding SQL.
I have asked some of my friends where they recommended me to check "JOIN" for my situation even though I dont think it does fit for my purpose.

The idea of mine is to store products information which are title, image and url and I have came to a conclusion to use:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    image TEXT,
    url TEXT UNIQUE, 
    added_date DATE
);
```

The reason of URL is UNIQUE is due to we cannot have same URL in the database as it will be duplicated which we do not want but then still I dont really understand why and how I should use JOIN in my situation.

So my question is, what would be the best way for me to store the products information? Which way would be the most benefit as well as best performance wise? If you are planning to use JOIN, I would gladly get more information why in that case. (There could be a situation where I could have over 4000 rows inserted overtime.)

I hope you all who are reading this will have a wonderful day! :)

Comment: Join to what? You have only 1 table. If you had other tables related to products then you would need joins.

Comment: Using JOIN should never be a goal when starting to learn SQL. JOIN is used to combine information from different tables. Currently you only show one table and it is not clear why you feel the need to use JOIN.    Finally the JOIN is covered in [Lesson 7](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_outer_joins).

Comment: @forpas Right, thats what I also thought. For me I dont see the reason to have two tables and thats what I also wanted to understand if I should split it to multiple tables or if I should keep it to 1 table as it is now.

Comment: @Luuk Yupp I did cover and for me, by looking the Lesson. I do understand that the lesson is meant to learn but in that example I dont really see the reason why they didn't create one table and combined it from the beginning, wouldn't that make more sense to have it together as one table instead of multiple? (If it was not for the lesson purpose)

Comment: If you have data, i.e. productgroup, which can have more than 1 field per productgroup, then it would be wise to create a second table `ProductGroup`, and not store something like `ProductGroupName` multiple times in the table `Products`.

Comment: @Luuk Ahh I see. well that would make sense. I assume the way I have it now shouldn't be needed to split it into multiple groups then. The only thing I could think of is to create another column called `StoreName` which I could create tables for stores but that also doesn't make sense if I have e.g. 50 different store names, that would be 50 different tables which isn't really good either. But after all that, the code that I have written in my thread would be consider as good in that case?

Comment: No, you should create one table `Stores`, with the fields `StoreID`  and `StoreName`. The tabl could hold 50 records, and in your `Products` table you only add `StoreID`. This `Products.StoreID` can then be JOINed to `Stores` to find the name of the store.

Comment: @Luuk You said `, and in your Products table you only add StoreID.`... where should I in that case add rest of the products such as title, image, url in that case? Inside the Products table?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have added the word `only`.... 

Comment: @Luuk If you want you could write this as the answer. I would still need to learn how I can add the correct ID when inserting but thats a problem for later. It was cool approach!

Comment: I suggest you take a short break from the SQL tutorial. Spend a little time on `Normalization`. Normalization is the underlying principle for database design and an understanding of it essential for good design. See a [decent tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-normalization).  It is a long tutorial, but then it is a huge topic. At this point no need to go beyond 3rd/BCNF.

Comment: @Belayer I could not more than agree with you. I do believe I would need to understand the normalization more and more even though I dont going to do a huge project out of this but of course more knowledge the better :)

Comment: Normalizing small projects pays huge benefits down the road.  You get into the habit of doing it correctly, then large projects are just bugger, but not necessarily harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using stores.

```
CREATE TABLE stores (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name TEXT
    -- add more fields if needed
);


CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL, 
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    image TEXT,
    url TEXT UNIQUE, 
    added_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, store_id)
);


ALTER TABLE products
ADD  CONSTRAINT "FK_products_stores" FOREIGN KEY ("store_id")
        REFERENCES stores (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: As I have written together with @Luuk in the comments. I think the approach could be abit different if I added "store" as inside the products. As Luuk described. `you should create one table Stores, with the fields StoreID and StoreName. The table could hold 50 records, and in your Products table you add StoreID, title, image, url and added_date. This Products.StoreID can then be JOINed to Stores to find the name of the store.` - Would that be something you could also see as a good approach?

Comment: Any reason why you use `without time zone` ?

Comment: With modern Postgres versions (>= 10) `identify` columns [are recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) over serial

Comment: 1. In case of your product depend on stores you need to add StoreId in the product table as  @Luuk described.  In that case, the primary key should be a composite key from Id, and StoreId. [documentation_composite_key](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/postgresql-composite-primary-keys-629). With this approach the products can start from 1 in each Store.    2."timestamp with time zone" mean the current time of your time zone.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could do a edit on your answer how it would look like with store as well? Then I can accept your answer as it is what I wanted after the discussion. Of course if you have the time! that would mean and I would appreciate it alot!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you have a typo - `identity`, not identify

Comment: Looking foward! :)

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I am abit confused with the Alter part. It would be nice if you could explain it. I am not able to understand how I am able to INSERT when you have a ALTER like that :(

Comment: With "ALTER" you can change the definition of a table. (in this case, adding a foreign key constraint). Also, it can be used for adding or deleting columns. [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html) ,  [foreign_key_doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-fk.html)

Comment: Good to know! Thank you so much :)